# How to determine type of password encryption being used?

Tags: laravel, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I inherited a web application (which was very poorly constructed). Currently I am trying to figure out which password encryption process is being used. This is a laravel application and an example of one of the passwords used is:

```
$2y$10$XtmUr.U0tm7PEVwgypqdmuwYluPdygK0GSBE08Y/43NbnLCRBMtWm
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to which encryption script is being used?

Comment: Laravel uses bcrypt by default

Comment: Also passwords are *hashed*, not *encrypted*. `$2y$10$` tells you it's Bcrypt (see e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108789/72084) with a work factor of 10, the rest is the salt and the hash.

Comment: **"which was very poorly constructed"**, **"encryption script"**, oh boy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel uses bcrypt (via PHP's native [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function) to hash passwords.